# Ceph got timeout

Tags: ceph

I upgraded my proxmox cluster from 6 to 7. After upgrading, Ceph services are not responding. Any command in the console, for example `ceph -s` hangs and does not return any result. And in the web interface I see `Error got timeout (500)` 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWcUA.png)

In the log I saw the error cluster [WRN] overall HEALTH_WARN noout flag (s) set; 1/4 mons down, quorum server-1, server-2, server-3
But when I try to execute `ceph osd unset noout` I see this error
`2021-12-03T18: 59: 17.068 + 0300 7fac8c30d700 0 monclient (hunting): authenticate timed out after 300`

Comment: can you check the log of mons